# Creating element inside IEnumerable instead of adding existing element to it

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, ienumerable

It is good to use such approach to add new item to custom collection? Not to add existing element, but create new element inside the collection? The method name "Add" is suitable for this case? (The purpose is hiding repositories.) Thanks.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int ID { get; }
    public Value1 { get; }
    public Value2 { get; }
}

public interface ICustomCollection : IEnumerable<MyObject>
{
    MyObject Add(value1, value2);
}

public class CustomCollection : ICustomCollection
{
    MyObjectFactory factory;
    MyObjectRepository repository;

    public IEnumerator<MyObject> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return repository.GetAllObjects();
    }

    public MyObject Add(value1, value2)
    {
        var newItem = factory.Create(value1, value2);
        repository.AddObject(newItem);
        return newItem;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: I think you need to ask your self, do i need a custom collection? The answer is almost always no. It seems you are using this collection to add items to a database?

Comment: "The answer is almost always no." -- do you have documented evidence to back up that pronouncement?

Comment: 'documented evidence' like a blog source from an Authority? What evidence do you seek? If you disagree lets discuss. That's what this is a discussion where professionals and novices share their insight...

Comment: I don't see any issue of having such methods. For instance, `DataRowCollection` has [similar method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Botonomous Yes, it is one of DDD layer abstractions purposed to hide DAL level

Comment: "The purpose is hiding repositories" - I don't get that. Why would you hide them?

Comment: Interesting, abstraction honestly. I have never heard of this approach and it sounds very interesting. To me this does what a service layer should do. Also this tightly couples the collection to the DAL. Interesting none the less.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need implement from `IEnumerable<T>`. It will be enough to introduce repository interface without it.

```
public interface IMyObjectRepostory
{
    IEnumerable<MyObject> GetAll();
    MyObject Add(value1, value2);
}

public class MyObjectRepostory
{
    public IEnumerable<MyObject> GetAll()
    {
        _repository.GetAllObjects();
    }

    MyObject Add(value1, value2)
    {
        var newItem = factory.Create(value1, value2);
        repository.AddObject(newItem);
        return newItem;
    }
}
```

Only thing which bother me, it that your repository depend on factory. Repository is database abstraction, main responsibility of database is read and write data. You should not use some "business" logic inside database operations.

But if you remove factory responsibility then you end up with simple repository interface

```
public interface IMyObjectRepostory
{
    IEnumerable<MyObject> GetAll();
    void Add(newMyObject);
}
```

and use it

```
IMyObjectRepository repository = new MyObjectRepository();
var allobjects = repository.GetAllObjects();

var newObject = factory.Create(value1, value2);
repository.Add(newObject);
```

You can consider one more layer of abstraction for encapsulating creation and saving.

```
public class MyObjectChooseBetterName
{
    private readonly IMyObjectRepository _repository;
    private readonly MyObjectFactory _factory;

    public MyObjectChooseBetterName(IMyObjectRepository repository,
                                    MyObjectFactory factory)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public MyObject CreateAndSave(object value1, object value2)
    {
        var newObject = _factory.Create(value1, value2);
        _repository.Add(newObject);
        return newObject;
    }
}
```

and use it

```
var manager = new MyObjectChooseBetterName(repository, factory);
var newObject = manager.CreateAndSave(value1, value2);
```

Comment: This approach breaks the `SRP` principle. In `DDD` the repository should have a method 'save' or 'persist' that accept a full `Aggregate` instance and persists it to the underlying persistence and should not attempt to encapsulate the creation of an `Aggregate`

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU - agree, read further - first sample was "refactored" OP approach, later I trying to explain why this is a wrong approach

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU *"In DDD the repository should have a method 'save' or 'persist'*" - disagree. You can give your Repository the shape of a simple collection (in fact that's the recommended way from the original DDD book) and handle saving at the Unit of Work level.

Comment: @guillaume31 Yes, an `add` would be a better name

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a collection to hide your repositories, since Repository already acts as a collection to the outside world.

> For each type of object that needs global access, create an object that can provide **the illusion of an in-memory
>   collection** of all objects of that type.

From Vernon's [Implementing DDD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577), p.401, quoting Evans' [original DDD book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) about Repositories.

Besides, cohesive collections usually don't create objects. They deal with existing objects (or primitive values).